# Load multiple file with PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Can there a one line for selecting multiple files path at once with PySimpleGUI

```
sg.PopupGetFile('Unique File select')
```

> Only one file selectable
>
> docs PopupGetFile(message, Message to show in the window
>             default_path='', Path browsing should start from
>             default_extension='', Which filetype is the default
>             save_as=False, Determines which dialog box stype to show
>             file_types=(("ALL Files", "*.*"),), Which filetypes are displayed
>             no_window=False, if True no window is displayed except the dialog box
>             size=(None,None), Size of window
>             button_color=None, Color of buttons
>             background_color=None, Color of window background
>             text_color=None, Color of text in window
>             icon=DEFAULT_WINDOW_ICON, Icon to show on taskbar
>             font=None, Font to use
>             no_titlebar=False, If True does not display a titlebar
>             grab_anywhere=False, if True can grab window anywhere to move it
>             keep_on_top=False, if True window will be on top of others
>             location=(None,None)) Location on screen to show window

Any API for multiple files without looping pattern ?

Comment: What does `PopupGetFile()` return when you select multiple files?

Comment: sg.PopupGetFile('blabla') => 'C:\test.txt'

Comment: My guess is that, as its based on Tkinter, multiple files is not a thing.

Comment: Yes in Tkinter it is,this why I was wondering using it directly but simple stuff PySimpleGUI is quite adapted : files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select files')

Answer (score 8):

Here is a "one-line" solution like you are seeking....

It allows you to select multiple files from a dialog box and will print the list of files as a list.  To be safe you should check to make sure the OK button was clicked by looking at the value of `event`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

event, values = sg.Window('Window Title').Layout([[sg.Input(key='_FILES_'), sg.FilesBrowse()], [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]).Read()

print(values['_FILES_'].split(';'))
```

### [ EDIT May 2022 ]

OK, well, here we are again at SO with the all-too-familiar problem of nothing dies here.... everything stays around, forever, including old problems with old solutions and are no longer a "problem".

While this is an interesting solution, it's from April 2019, only 9 months from the initial launch of PySimpleGUI.  This answer is ancient, it works, but it's teaching **bad conventions** and approaches.

This discussion uses the non-PEP8 `popup` calls, it's using the `Window.Layout` method which should not be used, and the key naming conventions recommended by the PySimpleGUI project **now** don't match.

I didn't know PEP8 existed when naming the original popup calls and it took a while to get aliases for all of them created that do adhere to PEP8 conventions once I figured out that rather grave error.

The PySimpleGUI documentation and demo programs are kept up to date... these answers on StackOverflow are not.  It's impossible to find all places on the internet where answers are posted and fix them.  But the ***documentation and sample programs on GitHub*** are possible to be maintained...and they are.

One "problem" that arises with the strong desire for PySimpleGUI to be backward compatible and thus enable programs written in the first month PySimpleGUI was released is that it doesn't prohibit using calls that are no longer recommended.

#### The ***new answer***

#### Ask on GitHub

The way I would answer this question today, in 2022, would be to first say please ask via an Issue on GitHub.  Not just for this project, but *for all projects, go to the project's home and ask the developers*.  When looking for answers, go THERE to find the answers.  You may find an answer here, but it could come at a cost.  Start with the project's documentation and then spread out from there.

*"Googling it" is not the best approach to programming.*  It will lead you to old, possibly bad information.  Their algorithm is stupid, you, reader, ***are not***.

#### The popups

`popup_get_file` is the PEP8 compliant name of the popup call and should be what's used.  It now has a parameter called `multiple_files` that when set to `True` will allow your user to select more than 1 file.  Check out the call reference tab in the main documentation for details - http://www.PySimpleGUI.org

The description you'll find of that parameter is:

if True, then allows multiple files to be selected that are returned with ';' between each filename

### The Final Answer...

```py
files = sg.popup_get_file('Unique File select', multiple_files=True)
```

This is how you would perform the operation today to get multiple files via a popup call.

#### Thank you for your attention

It's a long-winded edit, but it's an important topic in a very broad sense.  I get wanting to ask the google-genie to get a quick answer, but quick answer isn't what makes solid product or even a good one.

Comment: That's it thanks ! I did not notice I could use FilesBrowse() instead of FileBrowse

Comment: An elegant answer. Just what I needed as well.

Comment: Ooooooo..... "elegant" in a comment... that gets my attention!  Thank you very much!  It's appreciated and you've drawn my attention to the need, again, to update the answer....